# Nested braces using cases

Tags: braces

I want to use nested braces but the following code is giving errors. What is wrong here? How can I correct it?

```
$\psi_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
    \begin{aligned}
        &1  &= &\ 2\\
        &3  &= &\ 4\\
        &5  &= &\ 6\\
        &7  &= &\ 8\\
        \begin{rcases}
            &9  &= & 10\\
            &11 &= & 12
        \end{rcases} \text{13}
    \end{aligned}
\end{cases}
$\\
```

Comment: Did you load `mathtools`?

Comment: Unrelated: does your aligned environment have two alignment columns?

Comment: `rcases` admits only two columns, so only one `&` per line is allowed. But your usage of `&` also in the `aligned` block is quite wrong. Could you post some image of how the output is supposed to look like?

Comment: When I made it two two columns, it worked. Actually, in my case each digit is an expression. Is there a way to use nested braces (big left opening brace and right small one) and still able to align at more than two columns?

Comment: I'm surprised that this is coded as in-line math rather than as a display environment.  The multiple `&` are following the pattern of the deprecated `eqnarray`, not what is defined with `amsmath`.  (I'm not able to experiment just now, but will try later.)

Comment: can it be done using \left and \right?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do this with a mixture of `\left` and `\right` delimiters. Null delimiters (like `\left.` and `\right.`) are corrected for using `\kern-\nulldelimiterspace`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% No column separation
  %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% Stretch out array display
  A = \left\{\begin{array}{ l }
    \begin{array}{ r<{{}} r }
      \phantom{11 ={}}& \phantom{12} \\[-\normalbaselineskip]% For alignment with next array
       1 =&  2 \\
       3 =&  4 \\
       5 =&  6 \\
       7 =&  8 \\
    \end{array} \\
    \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{array}{ r<{{}} r }
       9 =& 10 \\
      11 =& 12
    \end{array}\right\} \text{13}
  \end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\]

\end{document}
```

You could also add `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` for a more `align`-like spacing.